# MySQL Error 1064 but is not a reserved word

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query

```
    SELECT REPLACE(book.title,'','') AS "item-name", REPLACE(inventory.sku,'','') AS "sku", REPLACE(IF(inventory.sku IN (SELECT sku FROM qty_skus) , (SELECT qty_skus.quantity FROM qty_skus WHERE qty_skus.sku = inventory.sku LIMIT 1), inventory.quantity),'','') AS "quantity",
REPLACE(LEFT( CONCAT(IF(book_type.book_text IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(book_type.book_text," "), ""), IFNULL(defect.defect,""), " ", IFNULL(inventory.additional_note,""), " ", IFNULL(feature.feature, ""), " ", IFNULL(water.feature, ""), " ", IFNULL(note.note,""),
                            " " ), 2000),'','') AS "item-note",
REPLACE(IF(book.weight>3.99, "1", "2"),'','') AS "will-ship-internationally",     REPLACE(inventory.isbn13,'','') AS "product-id", REPLACE(inventory.ourPrice,'','') AS "price",
REPLACE(IF(book.weight>4.8 AND (inventory.ourPrice - inventory.cost) < 9, "n", "y"),'','') AS "expedited-shipping", REPLACE(book_condition.book_condition,'','') AS "item-condition",
REPLACE(concat(location.location,IF(inventory.fixed="1", " Fixed", "")),'','') AS "Location", REPLACE(book.author,'','') AS "author", REPLACE(book.publisher,'','') AS "publisher",
REPLACE(IF(book_condition.book_condition="New", "11", IF(book_condition.book_condition="Fine", "1", IF(book_condition.book_condition="Very Good", "2", IF(book_condition.book_condition="Good", "3", IF(book_condition.book_condition="Poor", "4", ""))))),'','') AS "condition-id",
        REPLACE(IF(inventory.cost < ((follette_title.usedbuying_price *1.37) OR (amtext.price*1.37) OR (nebraska.price *1.2) OR (tichenor.price *1.25)),IF(feature.book_type_3 = "DMG",inventory.cost,
        IF(book_condition.book_condition="Good",inventory.cost,
        IF(book_condition.book_condition="Poor",inventory.cost,IF(inventory.book_type_id = 3, inventory.cost,
        IF(inventory.commission_level = 1, IF(inventory.cost < ((follette_title.usedbuying_price *1.71) OR (amtext.price*1.71)),(max((follette_title.usedbuying_price*1.71) OR (amtext.price*1.71)),inventory.cost),
        (max((follette_title.usedbuying_price*1.37) OR (amtext.price*1.37) OR (nebraska.price *1.2) OR (tichenor.price *1.25))))))))),inventory.cost),'','') AS "Cost",
                    REPLACE(concat(IFNULL(buyer_type.buyer_type, ""),IFNULL(source.source, ""),IFNULL(inventory.source_date, ""),IFNULL(note.book_type_2, ""),IF(inventory.csmt=1, "CSMT", ""),IF(inventory.cu=1, "CU", ""),IF(inventory.manual=1, "manual", ""),IFNULL(book_type.book_code, ""),IF(water.book_type_4="WATER", "WATER", "")),'','')  AS "Source", REPLACE(book.pub_date,'','') AS "pubdate", REPLACE(book.binding,'','') AS "Media", REPLACE(book_condition.book_condition,'','') AS "condition",
                    REPLACE(IF(location.location="FBA", "AMAZON_NA", ""),'','') AS "fulfillment-center-id"
                    FROM inventory
                    LEFT JOIN defect ON inventory.defect_id = defect.defect_id
                    LEFT JOIN book_condition ON defect.condition_id = book_condition.condition_id
                    LEFT JOIN book_type ON inventory.book_type_id = book_type.book_type_id
                    LEFT JOIN book ON inventory.isbn13 = book.isbn13
                    LEFT JOIN feature ON inventory.feature_id = feature.feature_id
                    LEFT JOIN water on inventory.additional_feature = water.feature_id
                    LEFT JOIN note ON inventory.note_id = note.note_id
                    LEFT JOIN location ON inventory.location_id = location.location_id
                    LEFT JOIN source ON inventory.source_id = source.source_id
                    LEFT JOIN buyer_type ON source.buyer_type_id = buyer_type.buyer_type_id
                    LEFT JOIN follette_title on inventory.isbn13 = follette_title.isbn13
                    LEFT JOIN amtext on inventory.isbn13 = amtext.isbn13
                    LEFT JOIN nebraska on inventory.isbn13 = nebraska.isbn13
                    LEFT JOIN tichenor on inventory.isbn13 = tichenor.isbn13
                    WHERE inventory.upload = 1 AND inventory.ourPrice > 0 AND inventory.location_id > 0 limit 0,20
```

And I am getting the following error and I can't figure out why:

```
    [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))))),inventory.cost),'','') AS "Cost",                     REPLACE(concat(IFNULL(buyer_type.' at line 12
```

I looked at the reserve words as the error indicates, but I don't see cost as a reserved word.  HELP!!!!

Comment: You can't figure it out because how can you read this query?. You should try formatting it, since it's very likely that you are missing some parenthesis or some other syntax error. For example, you are mixing double quotes and single quotes there: `CONCAT(book_type.book_text," ")`, that should be `CONCAT(book_type.book_text,' ')`, and this is all over your query

Comment: Thanks, but I took this over in a pinch and need to have it fixed ASAP.  I have it as a php query so I can check the parenthesis and they all seem to match up as they should

Comment: put backticks around all your table and field names. Then it doesn't matter if you use a reserved name.

Comment: What about the single and double quotes?, and you could also wrapped your tables and columns on backticks for avoiding reserved words

Comment: Error 1064 designates a parse error and does not necessarily indicate the use of a reserved word. Probably a syntax error (parenthesis pairs, quotes, comma's, stuff like that)

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
    IF(inventory.commission_level = 1, IF(inventory.cost < ((follette_title.usedbuying_price *1.71) OR (amtext.price*1.71)),(max((follette_title.usedbuying_price*1.71) OR (amtext.price*1.71)),inventory.cost),
    (max((follette_title.usedbuying_price*1.37) OR (amtext.price*1.37) OR (nebraska.price *1.2) OR (tichenor.price *1.25))))))))),inventory.cost),'','') AS "Cost",
```

to

```
    IF(inventory.commission_level = 1, IF(inventory.cost < ((follette_title.usedbuying_price *1.71) OR  (amtext.price*1.71)),(max((follette_title.usedbuying_price*1.71) OR (amtext.price*1.71)),inventory.cost),
    (greatest((follette_title.usedbuying_price*1.37) ,(amtext.price*1.37) , (nebraska.price *1.2), (tichenor.price *1.25))))))))),inventory.cost),'','') AS "Cost",
```

you can t make  `max(a or b or c)` instead use `greatest(a,b,c)`